# Comando pipe() no windows

Tags: python, windows

Estou tentando uma comunicação simples entre processos, porém o filho `f_filho` nao está recebendo a mensagem enviada pelo pai.

Como resolver?

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from multiprocessing import Process,Pipe
import numpy as np

def f_filho(pipe):
    frase=pipe.recv()
    print frase

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pipe_pai,pipe_filho=Pipe()
    print('começando o programa')
    p=Process(target=f_filho , args=(pipe_filho,))
    p.start()
    pipe_pai.send(['ola meu filho'])  #inica comunicação pelo pipe para o filho
    pipe_pai.close()
    p.join()
    print('fiiim')
```

Comment: Não deveria ser uma leitura em laço? Não garanto que o pipe anônimo vá ser bloqueante na função `recv`, então não custa nada ler em laço